# PowerShell and PSSession Issues

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm sure this is an easy answer for somebody but I can't find it with my Google fu.

I've got a script that, amongst other things, enters a pssession and does a GCI on the system the pssession was entered into.  However, when I do that PoSH says the path doesn't exist.  When I do an enter pssession and then do an FQDN gci PoSH *does* return results.

Example:

```
Enter-PSSession server1 
gci 'c:\inetpub\mailroot\Queue'
gci '\\server1.domain.com\c$\inetpub\mailroot\Queue'
```

That returns:

```
gci : Cannot find path 'C:\inetpub\mailroot\Queue' because it does not exist.
......
Directory: \\server1.domain.com\c$\inetpub\mailroot\Queue
insert folder contents here
```

Why is this happening and how do I get PoSH to enter the PSSession and then start processing the rest of the script?

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` is _for interactive use only_ - use `Invoke-Command` instead

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I can't believe I forgot something so basic.